# Having trouble with some media while using Firefox in Ubuntu.

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, adobe-flash, twitter

[image: Twitter Screenshot on Firefox (Ubuntu)]

I just started using Firefox in Ubuntu today. While on Twitter, I noticed some avatars not showing up, but just their description as seen in the screen shot below. Any idea what could cause this? Also, I need to d/l Adobe Flash so I can get other media to work online. It gives me the option to d/l it but then takes me to the Flash file with no option to install. Any ideas with this as well? Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 0):

nearly all flash problems can be solved in Ubuntu using this simple extension to Firefox.

[Flash Aid Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flash-aid)

Keep us posted if the image problem persists somehow.